# Using a class that inherits System.Windows.Controls.Control inside XAML

Tags: wpf

I have wpf application with the following xaml as the mainwindow

```
<Window x:Class="Video_Editor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

I also have a class that inherits 'Control' called 'MyControl'.
How do I make it possible to put an instance of that MyControl inside the xaml.

Something like this

```
<Grid>
  <MyControl/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the [XAML namespace mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="Video_Editor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceContainingMyControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that, if the control is in a different assembly (DLL), you'll need to use `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceContainingMyControl;assembly=YourLibrary"`.